# How to assign date to shell variable?

Tags: command-line, bash

Given a parameter `$1`, I want to subtract 5 minutes from that time, and echo it (later reuse the variable).

```
echo $1
time5=date -d "$1 5 minutes ago" +'%H:%M'
echo ${time5}
```

Call with: `./script.sh 16:55`

Result:

> prints  16:50
>
> ./script.sh: line 2: -d: command not found

Why can't I assign the date to the variable `time5`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `$()` operator for this:

```
echo "$1"
time5=$(date -d "$1 5 minutes ago" +'%H:%M')
echo "$time5"
```